# Prove that a set of polynomials forms a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf V$ be the set of polynomials of the form $a + bx + cx^2$ such that $a + b + c = 0$. Show that the set $\mathbf S$ $= \{ 1-x^2, x-x^2 \}$ forms a basis for $\mathbf V$.

I know that I need to show that $span(\mathbf S) = \mathbf V$ as well show that $\mathbf S$ is linearly independent.

By inspection, it's obvious that $\mathbf S$ is linearly independent since it only contains two elements which are not multiples of each other. However, I'm struggling trying to show that $span(\mathbf S) = \mathbf V$.

I tried making the following argument but it doesn't seem right at all:

Let $k_1, k_2 \in \Bbb R$. Observe that $k_1(1-x^2) + k_2(x-x^2) = k_1 + k_2x + (-k_1 - k_2)x^2$. Then the sum of the coefficients of this polynomial is: $k_1 - k_1 + k_2 - k_2 = 0 + 0 = 0$. Thus, any polynomial in $\mathbf V$ can be represented as a linear combination of the vectors in $\mathbf S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a+b\,x+c\,x^2\in V$ if and only if $c=-a-b$. It follows that $a+b\,x+c\,x^2\in V$ if and only if
$$
a+b\,x+c\,x^2=a+b\,x+(-a-b)\,x^2=a(1-x^2)+b(x-x^2)
$$
This proves that $\{1-x^2,x-x^2\}$ spans $V$.

To prove that $\{1-x^2,x-x^2\}$ is linearly independent suppose that
$$
a(1-x^2)+b(x-x^2)=0\tag{1}
$$
Plugging $x=0$ into (1) implies $a=0$. Plugging $x=-1$ into (1) implies $b=0$. Hence $\{1-x^2,x-x^2\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat a little here:

1. It is clear that $dim(V)=2$. That means that if for some subspace $W\subset{V}$ $dim(W)=2$, then $W=V$.
2. You already know that $span(S)$ is a space and that $dim(S)=2$. Now we just need to show that $span(S)\subset{V}$:
   $$
   \forall a,b: a^2+b^2>0 \,\, a(1-x^2)+b(x-x^2)=a+bx+(b-a)x^2
   $$
   and the sum of coefficients of this polynomial is 0.

So, $span(S)=V$ and $S$ is a basis of $span(S)$ by definition so $S$ is a basis of $V$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

The set of polynomials of degree 2 is a 3 dimensional vector space.
i.e. the set of degree 2 polynomials is all vectors of the for $a + b x+ cx^2$.
$\bf V$ is a two dimensional subspace as $c = -b-a$.

Any two independent vectors that are in $\bf V$ can serve as a basis for $\bf V$.